# How do I install g++ for Fedora?

Tags: c++, linux, g++, fedora, dnf

How do I install `g++` for Fedora Linux? I have been searching the `dnf` command to install `g++` but didn't find anything.

How do I install it?

I have already installed `gcc`

Comment: You probably need to install a package perhaps named `g++-4.7` (or `g++-4.6`).

Answer (score 311):

The package you're looking for is confusingly named [`gcc-c++`](http://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=gcc-c%2b%2b).

Comment: I got this error during the install: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=494006. Running `yum clean metadata` resolved the error and I was able to install gcc-c++.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is discoverable by doing `sudo yum install /usr/bin/g++` (or `sudo yum install /usr/bin/g++`).

Comment: Alternately, without having to know exactly where the binary ends up, you can do `yum whatprovides '*bin/g++'` or even `yum whatprovides '*/g++'`.

Answer (score 148):

instead of g++ you have to write gcc-c++

```
sudo dnf install gcc-c++
```

Comment: I have already installed gcc. I have been compiling `c` using the same

Comment: g++ is like an aditional for gcc, so if you want g++ the package you need is gcc-c++, try it...

Comment: with 22 its rather `sudo dnf install gcc-c++ -y`

Answer (score 41):

You should exec:

```
dnf install gcc-c++
```

Answer (score 17):

Run the command bellow in a terminal emulator:

```
sudo dnf install gcc-c++
```

Enter password and that's it...

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem. At least I could solve it with this:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++
```

Hope it solves your problem too.

Answer (score 9):

try
`sudo dnf update` and then 
`sudo dnf install gcc-c++`

Comment: Update is not required. This is where fedora differs from debian

Comment: `update` will update the current software, though. (like `upgrade` under Debian) It could be useful.

Comment: It's always a good idea to update the current software before adding new packages. It's not necessary, but you can get into some weird situations (particularly around multiarch) if you don't.

Answer (score 6):

Since Fedora 22 yum has been deprecated so the commands given in other answers will actually fire up 'Dandified yum' i.e. `dnf`. So the new command to install g++ in recent distributions is

```
su -c "dnf install gcc-c++"
```

As of Nov 2015 this installs the 5.1.1 version.
Also note that in Fedora 23 when I gave the command `g++ -v`, Fedora automatically asked me if I want to install gcc-c++ package. I think thats nice.(After the install it also ran the command `g++ -v` for me)
Only nit pick that I can do about it is that instead of a progress indicator you just get `* Downloading packages...` message which you may not like if you are on a slow internet connection.

Answer (score 4):

In the newer distribution you can just type command as blow

```
su root
dnf update
dnf install gcc-c++
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `gcc-g++` package does not exist.

Comment: Again, note `c++` not `g++` in the package name.

Comment: As of now (2020-04-20) both ```dnf install g++``` and ```dnf install gcc-g++``` resolve to ```gcc-c++``` (and tell me it's already installed :)). [for the sake of future visitors]

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me on Fedora 36:

```
sudo dnf groupinstall c-development
```

It will install the cc (gcc) and c++ (g++):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just make a sample 'Hello World' Program and try to compile it using "g++ sam.cpp" in terminal, and it will ask you if you wish to download the g++ package. Press y to install.

Comment: I believe this only is the case in some spins.

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps to install and configure C++ compiler i.e. g++ compiler in Fedora OS -

- Check for update - `sudo dnf update`
- Upgrade the packages - `sudo dnf upgrade`
- Install the g++ compiler - sudo dnf install gcc-c++
- Verify the installed version of compiler - sudo dnf install gcc-c++