# How do I install PyQt5 on Fedora 23 (Python 2)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, fedora, pyqt5, fedora-23

I followed the instructions at https://github.com/pyqt/python-qt5/wiki/Compiling-PyQt5-on-Ubuntu-12.04 and <s>get this error:</s>

```
$ python configure.py --qmake ~/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake --sip-incdir ../sip-4.16.5/siplib --verbose
Querying qmake about your Qt installation...
Determining the details of your Qt installation...
/home/david/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake -o qtdetail.mk qtdetail.pro
make -f qtdetail.mk
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I../../Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include -I../../Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/include/QtCore -I. -o qtdetail.o qtdetail.cpp
make: g++: Command not found
qtdetail.mk:524: recipe for target 'qtdetail.o' failed
make: *** [qtdetail.o] Error 127
Error: Failed to determine the detail of your Qt installation. Try again using
the --verbose flag to see more detail about the problem.
```

Could someone help me here?

Thanks.

EDIT: I solved this by installing `gcc-c++` with dnf, but now I get this error when running `make`: https://gist.github.com/TheInitializer/4edca67ee64bf7a86a850fe839985297

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: do you have `g++` installed? `make: g++: Command not found` seems suspect. Verify that this worked: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
you should be able to run the command `g++` from a shell.

Comment: @busfault Fedora does not have `apt`. You need `dnf install gcc` or so ...

Comment: @Jakuje tried that already

Comment: @busfault ok, I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952913/how-do-i-install-g-for-fedora Will try and see how it goes

Comment: Installed it and now it seems to be working :D

Comment: configure.py ran successfully, running `make` now :D

Comment: `make` failed with this error message: https://gist.github.com/TheInitializer/4edca67ee64bf7a86a850fe839985297 updated the question. can anyone help with this?

Comment: Can you post error here?

Comment: @busfault it's a bit long, so I put it on gist. An interesting part of it is `error: ‘const sipAPIDef {aka const struct _sipAPIDef}’ has no member named ‘api_get_reference’`. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I kinda feel stupid.

PyQt5 has a dnf package.

I just ran `sudo dnf install PyQt5` and it installed.